# Multiple IP stacks

Tags: linux, ip

I have a linux box with two ethernet interfaces (eth0 & eth1) with two corresponding IPs. As per my understanding, currently they are served by 1 IP stack. Is it possible to install another IP stack with IP Stack 1 handling ethernet interface eth0 and the other IP stack handling eth1.

Comment: ... What could you *possibly* hope to accomplish by doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - sort of. maybe multiple routing tables and policy-based routing [ eg based on from which local ip packet is sent ] is what you search for?

if so - check [this](http://www.linuxhorizon.ro/iproute2.html) or [there](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-rule.html). it is doable... i load-balanced OUTGOING traffic in that way using couple of different connections [even from different isps], but in general with BGP - it's much more fun and less of hackery.